# Animating particles when adding a force field

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

I'm creating an animation with moving newspapers using planes and force fields. On the planes that act as newspapers I add a soft body, and on the ground plane I add collisions.

[image]

[image]

When i watch animation render results the newspapers move jerkily in some of the frames. What can affect the movement of the soft body? How to remove jerky animation?

I will be grateful for any help.